# Which Django internationalization files are being used?

Tags: django, text, internationalization

I can switch languages in my Django application by changing LANGUAGE_CODE in the Settings.py file for the application.

But I'm not sure where the actual text is coming from.

In path-to-django/contrib/auth/locale/, there are directories for many languages containing the translations of the text I'm displaying. But if I move an .mo file for a particular language to a new name, I still see text for that language -- even after I restart Django. So where does the text actually come from?

Also, for the 'en' locale, the translated text is always "" (empty string). Does ugettext_lazy just return its input string in that case? If not, where does the English text come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a system-wide Django installation that was being used, rather than my local installation.

By creating a locale directory within my app, I'm able to override the strings used in the system-wide installation. I just modify the .po file there, and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a difference, if you speak of translation in the django admin or within your application. The path you mentioned .../contrib/auth/locale refers to translations in the django admin.

For special translation within your application you should have a locale/ folder in your project. This folder is created when you run the django special script named "django-admin.py makemessages".

> The script runs over your project source tree or your application
> source tree and pulls out all strings marked for translation. It
> creates (or updates) a message file in the directory
> locale/LANG/LC_MESSAGES. In the de example, the file will be
> locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po.

For detailed explanation, please look at django i18n [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#how-to-create-language-files)

After you have created your message files (*.po) and after you have written your own translations in the message files, don't forget to compile them:

> **Compiling message files**
>
> After you create your message file -- and each
> time you make changes to it -- you'll need to compile it into a more
> efficient form, for use by gettext. Do this with the django-admin.py
> compilemessages utility.
>
> This tool runs over all available .po files and creates .mo files,
> which are binary files optimized for use by gettext. In the same
> directory from which you ran django-admin.py makemessages, run
> django-admin.py compilemessages like this:
>
> django-admin.py compilemessages
>
> That's it. Your translations are ready for use.

Comment: I'm using forms that are subclassed from standard Django forms, so they appear to use the locale information in the directory I mentioned. I don't need special translation for the application itself -- I want to modify Django strings for all applications. If I modify the .po files in that directory, though, and rerun compilemessages, the information does not seem to change. That fact, and the fact that moving the compiled .mo files to a different name does not change the behavior, is puzzling. There don't seem to be any other .mo files in my directory tree.

Comment: Could you please give us some sample code of what you do, and what you are expecting? Without that, it is difficult to understand, what you really mean.

Comment: I want to change one of the English translations in the en .po file, and have that show up in the application. That's all!